# Unknown characters with text2pdf.py

Tags: python, pdf

I must use a program what convert txt to pdf file like text2pdf.py but I have some problems. In my text file I have some characters which arent ascii. Example `(ü, ğ ,ş ,•, ’ )` So when I converted the text file to pdf, there are unknown characters like `â€¢, ÅŸÄ±`
How can I correct these and display well these characters with text2pdf.py program or is there a easy way to convert txt file to pdf ? Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [text2pdf.py](https://bitbucket.org/vgavro/text2pdf/src/56fb9b3e1c73/text2pdf.py) like so, use `-c` param.

Comment: As we can [see](https://bitbucket.org/vgavro/text2pdf/src/56fb9b3e1c73/text2pdf.py#cl-150) you can use like: `text2pdf.py -c UTF8 INPUT.TXT OUTPUT.PDF` (in this script UTF8 set as default).